# Understanding Mercurial Branching

Tags: mercurial, graph, branch, explorer

I'm learning mercurial and I went to commit some changes and I got the message along the lines of "new head created" -- though I could have sworn that I did an hg pull and an hg update prior to doing new work.

I then got confused so I did a merge to try to get out of the mess. The single file I'm working on is fine (again I'm using only one file as I try to learn HG).  I can't post my image (not enough points) but I tried to recreate it below.

When I created the tag seo_v_1.0 did I automatically create a branch?  In other hg repos I simply create a tag, push the changes and keep going.

Can someone help me decipher what I did here?  The only change I made on the repo before the merge thing was that I committed the "up to 33" changset. So maybe -- according to my branch diagram here below -- I was already in the branch but didn't know it? 
Did the creation of tag seo_v_1.0 inadvertently create a branch?

Thanks in advance.

Note that the line out starts from "seo_v_1.0" to "added tag.."  and the line comes back in at "up to 33" to "default tip merge thing"

- default tip merge thing [this is in yellow] [and default is in green]

  - up to 33
  - added tag seo_v_1.1 for changeset xxxx
  - seo_v1.1 cleared colors [this is in yellow]
  - added tag seo_v_1.0 for changeset xxxx
- seo_v_1.0-completed  [this is in yellow]
- seo through section 2
- seo cross reference done
- initial commit

**Edit**: glog output added

```
@ changeset: 9:8637aa6d738f 
|\ tag: tip 
| | parent: 8: 
| | parent: 7: 
| | 
| | summary: merge thing 
| | 
| o changeset: 8: 
| | parent: 4: 
| | 
| | summary: up to 33 
| | 
o | changeset: 7: 
| | 
| | summary: Added tag seo_v_1.1 for changeset de5f8c81840f 
| | 
o | changeset: 6: 
| | tag: seo_v_1.1 
| | 
| | 
| | summary: cleared left col colors 
| | 
o | changeset: 5: 
|/ 
| 
| summary: Added tag seo_v_1.0 for changeset c13bd5d3cc09 
| o changeset: 4: 
| tag: seo_v_1.0 
| 
| summary: -completed cross-reference
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you show us the output of "hg glog" with the graphlog extension enabled?

```
hg --config extensions.graphlog="" glog
```

You can strip most of the changes, but please leave at least enough changes to show:

- The tag operation
- The merge you did

Comment: @    changeset:   9:8637aa6d738f
|\   tag:         tip
| |  parent:      8:
| |  parent:      7:
| |  
| |  summary:  merge thing
| |
| o  changeset:   8:
| |  parent:      4:
| |  
| |  summary:  up to 33
| |
o |  changeset:   7:
| |    
| |  summary:  Added tag seo_v_1.1 for changeset de5f8c81840f
| |
o |  changeset:   6:
| |  tag:         seo_v_1.1
| |  
| |  
| |  summary:     cleared left col colors
| |
o |  changeset:   5:
|/   
| 
|    summary:     Added tag seo_v_1.0 for changeset c13bd5d3cc09
|
o  changeset:   4:
|  tag:         seo_v_1.0
|  
|  summary:     -completed cross-reference

Comment: @David I put the log content into your question, since SO does not allow preformatted text in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a tag definitely didn't create a named branch, but it could have created an anonymous branch, because the act modifies the `.hgtags` file and then commits.

Give this a quick read; it's immensely helpful:

http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/

I'm sure with the hg glog output Giorgos requested we can help you figure out what happened, but with a little more understanding from that guide you'll probably see it yourself.